# Choice of bins for histograms with relatively few datapoints

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, binning

Consider a plot with multiple [histograms in matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# Use the same seed for reproducibility.
random.seed(10586)

data1 = [random.gauss(1e-4, 3e-2) for _ in range(10**3)] + [0.3]
data2 = [random.gauss(1e-2, 3e-3) for _ in range(10**3)] + [0.4]
data3 = [0.2]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plt.xlim(xmin=0, xmax=0.8)
    plt.yscale('log')
    n1, bins1, patches1 = plt.hist(data1, bins='auto', alpha=0.6)
    n2, bins2, patches2 = plt.hist(data2, bins='auto', alpha=0.6)
    n3, bins3, patches3 = plt.hist(data3, bins='auto', alpha=0.6)
    bin_options = ['auto', 'fd', 'doane', 'scott', 'rice', 'sturges', 'sqrt']
    plt.show()
```

However, the third dataset has only one datapoint,
so when we use `plt.hist(data3, bins='auto')`
we get a long bar stretched across the x-range,
and can no longer see that its value is 0.2:

[image: stretched out]

(This is most apparent with just one datapoint,
but it's an issue with e.g. two or three also.)

One way to avoid this it to just re-use the bins of another dataset.
For example, for `plt.hist(data3, bins=bins1)`,
we can see `data3` just fine:

[image: what we want]

However, if we use the other data set via `bins=bins2`,
the bins are too narrow and we cannot see `data3` at all:

[image: all gone]

How can we ensure that a histogram with relatively few points is visible,
but still see its value on the x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure you see a bar, even if it is too narrow to comprise a pixel, you could give it an edgecolor,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
random.seed(10586)

data2 = [random.gauss(1e-2, 3e-3) for _ in range(10**3)] + [0.4]

plt.xlim(0, 0.8)
plt.yscale('log')

n2, bins2, patches2 = plt.hist(data2, bins='auto', alpha=0.6, edgecolor="C0")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or use `histtype="stepfilled"` to create a polygon, because individual bar's aren't distinguishable with that many bins anyways,

```
n2, bins2, patches2 = plt.hist(data2, bins='auto', alpha=0.6, histtype="stepfilled")
```

[image]

The latter also has the advantage of obeying the alpha, which is otherwise not seen due to the overlap of the bars. Also it should be a faster drawing one single shape rather than some 1000 bars.